# Sharepoint - Multiple document upload - HTTP 'post' verb not allowed

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net, upload, httpverbs

When attempting to upload any number of documents, including very small files, seems to succeed- but subsequently redirects to an error page indicating the following:

```
/_layouts/error.aspx?ErrorText=The%20HTTP%20verb%20POST%20used%20to%20access%20path%20%27%2F%5Fvti%5Fbin%2Fshtml%2Edll%2FSiteCollectionDocuments%2FForms%2FUpload%2Easpx%27%20is%20not%20allowed%2E
```

**The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/_vti_bin/shtml.dll/SiteCollectionDocuments/Forms/Upload.aspx' is not allowed.**

Any ideas as to why HTTP POST would be denied for this operation?

**Error in event log looks like this:**

```
Critical error has occured but the exception object has already been cleared

Current Url: /_vti_bin/shtml.dll/SiteCollectionDocuments/Forms/Upload.aspx
User Login: xxxxxxx
User is Authenticated: True

Performance Counters
% Processor Time Total: 0
Processor Queue Length: 1
ASP.NET Request Queued Total: 1
.NET CLR Exceptions, # of Exceps Thrown: 55

PATH_INFO: /_vti_bin/shtml.dll/SiteCollectionDocuments/Forms/Upload.aspx
PATH_TRANSLATED: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\isapi\shtml.dll
```

Comment: Are you getting an error on the server side (in the Event Log or the SharePoint logs) when this occurs?

Comment: Shows the error on the client side.

Comment: Can you clarify that for me? Does that mean the server side shows the same error as the client side? Or that there is no error on the server side, just on the client?

Comment: Error only shows for the client.  Error on the server indicates there has been a critical error, but it was cleared before the exception made it into the event log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your wildcard application mapping in IIS.

The HTTP POST request could be rerouted incorrectly and cause the request to fail to the Upload.aspx page.

Comment: That fixed the particular issue in question, but broke other things such as the ability to delete documents.  

As it turns out, there was an HTTP module that was causing this url to be processed incorrectly.  I added a bypass for "/_vti_bin/shtml.dll/SiteCollectionDocuments/Forms/Upload.aspx" and this solved the issue with no side effects.